# You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint?

Tags: android, google-play, signing

Guys I am trying to update my app on google play and I am getting the error below
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the uploaded certificate. You must use the same certificate. The uploaded certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 17:FC:08:9C:D6:4A:5A:E5:14:A7:4D:69:07:94:69:B4:36:20:46:CF ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK that you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 3D:E4:88:9C:ED:36:19:F0:36:63:BA:02:30:14:7D:B3:9C:FD:7B:07 ]
I have used all StackOverflow solution not working please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Not dublicate I have used all the solution please help me

Comment: Have you used the same .jks file or keystore file?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan

Comment: Yes I used the jks and keystore file

Comment: I mean have you used the same keystore file which you have used for first time deployment to PlayStore. We get above error when we use different keystore

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan Yes the same